# Visual Studio 2015 Debugger remains active after application is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

There is an old similar question without answer so I've decided to ask if someone has a hint on this:
I've installed a new Windows 10 Laptop with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
After setting all up, I've checked out one of my solution, that is working perfectly on Windows 7 and VS 2013 and I have the problem indicated on the subject.
I start the application, I can debug it or stop the debugger without problems, but if I close the application the application closes but the debugger remains active.
The application is a WPF Windows application, the Shutdown Mode is set to ShutDown when the main window is closed.

Now, I know that maybe Windows 10 is different and Visual Studio 2015 is different, but this is not a normal behavior in my opinion.
if you have any clue, maybe I've lost some new setting?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the application properly exit (e.g. no longer in task manager) if you try to run it outside of the debugger and then close it? Sounds like your vshost is not picking up on the fact that the main thread of your app is terminating.

Comment: Click the "pause" button on the debugger, I'm guessing you have a foreground thread that is still running.

Comment: I've found the issue, it is due to the Splash Screen, that has been written by a colleague. The Splash Screen is a Singleton class and uses a separate thread to show information on screen while the application loads modules and other things. But the thread seems to remain active after the splash is closed and that is why the application remains active. What is strange is why this happens only on Windows 10 and not also on Windows 7

Comment: I don't know if it's better begin another question so I'll add here for now: I've investigated more with my colleague and the Applications Shutdown correctly when launched outside VS; trying a step by step debug the problem looks being in BeginInvokeShutdown not called correctly in debug mode. I don't know if this is due to VS not running with Admin Rights in Win10 or if there is a real issue in our code. If you have any clue thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing a simple repair of Visual Studio installation.